# Unix.fork を呼ぶと fork 前のトップレベルの式が再度実行されてしまう

Tags: ocaml

Unix モジュールの fork 関数を呼ぶと、 fork 前のトップレベルの式が再度実行されてしまいます。 fork 前のコードを fork 後に実行されないようにしたいのですが、どう修正すればよいのでしょうか。

コード:

```
let () =
  Printf.printf "hello, world!\n";
  ignore @@ Unix.fork ()
```

実行結果 (ネイティブコードにコンパイルしての実行です):

```
hello, world!
hello, world!
```

実行環境:

- Mac OS X 10.2.5
- OCaml 4.04.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Printf.printf` のバッファリングの問題だと思います。`%!` を使って flush してあげます。

```
let () =
  Printf.printf "hello, world!\n%!";
  match Unix.fork () with
  | 0 -> ()
  | _ -> ignore @@ Unix.wait ()
```

---

補足: トップレベルの式が2回実行されているわけではなさそうということは、入出力以外の副作用を使ってみると推測できます。たとえば参照を使ってみました。

```
let r = ref 0
let () =
  r := !r + 1;
  Printf.printf "all: %d\n%!" !r;
  match Unix.fork () with
  | 0 -> Printf.printf "child: %d\n%!" !r
  | _ -> Printf.printf "parent: %d\n%!" !r;
         ignore @@ Unix.wait ()
```

```ml
(* 実行結果 *)
all: 1
parent: 1
child: 1
```

参考: caml-list に同様の問題が投稿されていたのを見つけました: ["different behaviour of Unix.fork on FreeBSD and Linux"](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/caml-list/2003-05/msg00162.html)

Comment: なるほど、バッファだったんですね。ありがとうございます！私も質問後に参照で確認しました。検証が甘かったです。